# How many ways to arrange 2 distinct things in 3 ways?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm wondering how one would more rigorously figure out how to arrange 2 *distinct* objects in 3 spots. I believe the answer to be 8, since if we take one item to be *a* and the other to be *b*, you can run through the possibilities:

$$aaa, bbb, aab, bba, bab, aba, abb, baa$$

so the answer is 8.

How would one figure this out without manually running through all the possibilities? Further, if we denoted the number of *distinct* objects as *k* and the number of spots *m*, how would one arrive at the general formula?

Thanks.

Comment: In the title suggest "spots" not "ways" (as in body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of $3$ spots has  $2$ choices, so total $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2=8$ ways. In general $k^m.$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks.